# Why does hive on tez run twice as fast sometimes?

Tags: hive, apache-tez

I've run some experiments with `hive` on `tez`. I have a query that 80% of the time runs for about 45 seconds and the rest of the time runs for about 24 seconds. What could that rare speedup be attributed to?

Comment: are you measuring the time by executing query on dedicated queue, if not please do so.

Comment: @GaurangShah how? In Yarn? And I run queries in a sandbox, so it probably should not matter?

Comment: it shouldn't.  however I don't think sandbox is the best to measure the time.  if you are using docker your resources will be shared with other containers and host machine. if you are using VM, I think it would be more appropriate

Comment: @GaurangShah yes, I run it inside virtual box.